# Get AD Computers from list of members in O365 Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to get a list of members from a group in O365, then use that list to get all Active Directory computers.

To get the list of members:

```
$list = Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity "Group Name" | Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -LinkType Member | Select DisplayName
```

Then to get the computers:

```
foreach($user in $list) {
  Get-ADComputer -Filter "Description -like '$user'" -Property Name,Description | Select -Property Name
}
```

But nothing happens when I run the second command. I can see $list is populated when I call it. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or a better way to do this? Please keep in mind I don't know much powershell at all.

Comment: Try changing `"Description -like '$user'"` to `"Description -like '$($user.DisplayName)'"` or `"Description -like '*$($user.DisplayName)*'"`

Answer (score 2):

Changed `"Description -like '$user'"` to `"Description -like '$($user.DisplayName)'"`